# Flutter, Dart Split sentence every one character to 2 characters size, for flutter custom tts project

Tags: flutter, dart, split, text-to-speech

Example:

var sentence = (hello there, I am Bob.)

var result = [
'he',
'el',
'll',
'lo',
' ',
'th',
'he',
'er',
're',
',',
' ',
'I',
' ',
'am',
' ',
'bo',
'ob',
'.']

I've found here working example, though it is in Javascript and I don't really know how to adopt it for Dart, and not sure how will behave once white space and punctuation is added in. Punctation and white space I need always split on its own not in combination with letters, I need them as well, as I will use them to add pauses in between words and sentences.

Thank you

```js
    var a = 12345678;
    a= a.toString();
    var arr=[];
    for (var i =0; i<a.length-1; i++) {
     arr.push(Number(a[i]+''+a[i+1]));
    }
    
    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is having same issue, this is how I solved it

```
void main(String string) {
var test = "I Hello there I am Bob 23!";

List<String> nameArray = test.split('');

for (int curIndex = 0; curIndex < nameArray.length; curIndex++) {

if (curIndex >= 1 && nameArray[curIndex].contains(new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]')) && nameArray[curIndex-1].contains(new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'))) {
      print(nameArray[curIndex-1] + nameArray[curIndex]); // checks if current curIndex and previous curIndex are letters, if so returns previous and curent letters joined
    } else {
if  (curIndex >= 1 && nameArray[curIndex].contains(new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]')) && nameArray[curIndex+1].contains(new RegExp(r'[a-zA-Z]'))) {
      null; // checks if curIndex and next curIndex are letters, if so returns null
  }else{
    print(nameArray[curIndex]);
  }

}
}
}
```

Which returns

```
I

He
el
ll
lo
 
th
he
er
re
 
I
 
am
 
Bo
ob
 
2
3
!
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions to split the sentence. For example:

```
void main() {
  var exp = RegExp('([A-Za-z]{1,2}|[,!.?\s ])');
  var str = "hello there, I am Bob.";
  var matches = exp.allMatches(str);

  for (var m in matches) {
    print(m.group(0));
  }
}
```

This looks for letters (A-Z or a-z) in groups of either 1 or 2, or single punctuation characters (,!.?) \s represents a white space.

Running the above would produce:

```
he
ll
o
 
th
er
e
,
 
I
 
am
 
Bo
b
.
```

Comment: Thank, though it I need it like this [var result = [ 'he', 'el', 'll', 'lo', ' ', 'th', 'he', 'er', 're', ',', ' ', 'I', ' ', 'am', ' ', 'bo', 'ob', '.']. Will check if I can see how to adopt your code if possible

Comment: Yes, rather than printing it as I have in my example, you can push the result onto a list. That should give you the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
void main() {
    var a = "1234!5678";
    a = a.toString();
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {

        if (a[i + 1] == '!') {
            continue;
        }
        if (a[i] == '!') {
            arr.add(a[i]);
            continue;
        }
        arr.add(a[i] + '' + a[i + 1]);

    }

    print(arr);
}
```

I don't know dart much but I wrote this simple algorithm on dartpad and it works

Comment: Thank, is this writen in proper dart code or you just wrote variation on JavaScript code? As it is not working in DartPad?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, yeah it works, thank you, though there is still issue that it groups white space and punctuation with letters, it should always separate white space and punctuation marks separately on its own example = "how I am?, result = ['ho','ow',' ','I','am','?'] . Trying to figure if I can get there, but it looks really promising